# About opencv-python 3.4.3

Tags: python, opencv, python-wheel

I really wanna ask about opencv-python wheel file.

I tried installing "opencv_python-3.4.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl" on the site that is "https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv". But, it is deleted.(it was there before 10 months ago.)

I tried to find it but couldn't.

Could you tell me where to install it OR what can substitute that?

Comment: what if you do normally `pip install opencv-python` ? Do you get errors?

Comment: no. But, Is it Ok to install just 'opencv-python' instead 'opencv_python-3.4.3-cp36-cp36w-win32.whl'?

Comment: BTW: you can also try `pip install opencv-python==3.4.3`. Or list all avaliable versions  `pip install opencv-python==` . On Linux I see version `3.4.3.18`

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, which solve my pressure!  ˵ ͡ᵔ ͜ʟ ͡ᵔ ˵